# re-direct /Documents to a folder on a ubuntu server

Tags: domain-server

I hope this is an easy task to implement basically I 'need' to point the currently logged in user's documents,etc to a folder on the server. I know this an easy task on a windows server and client through group policy.

Comment: I think you want LDAP - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryHowto - but I am not sure as I find your question vague

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I will re phrase, on a "windows" network you can configure the client to re-direct the users documents folder to an actual folder that resides on the server, thus giving the impression that the users documents 'follow' them as they login to different machines.

Comment: On Linux it is called active directory, see the link I gave you. I am not aware of any graphical configuration tool and it takes some time to configure.

Comment: RHEL has a graphical tool https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Configuring_Authentication.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just mount the network share on the Documents folder

Move any existing docs out of the local user Documents folder first.

Then add this to fstab

```
server.local:/srv/user/Documents /home/user/Documents  nfs  _netdev,auto 0 0
```

Change server.local to a valid dns name of your server.

Tell it to do the mounts now

```
mount -a
```

Now your local Documents folder points to your server location.

You would need your nfs server in place first, and nfs-tools installed locally.

This is a manual way to do it for one user on one workstation.  For multiple users or a generic version you'll need something smarter using LDAP or NSS.